# How do I get consistent values with influxdb non_negative_derivative?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

Using grafana with influxdb, I am trying to show the per-second rate of some value that is a counter.  If I use the `non_negative_derivative(1s)` function, the value of the rate seems to change dramatically depending on the time width of the grafana view.  I'm using the `last` selector (but could also use `max` which is the same value since it is a counter).

Specifically, I'm using:

`SELECT non_negative_derivative(last("my_counter"), 1s) FROM ...`

According to the [influxdb docs non-negative-derivative](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/query_language/functions/#non-negative-derivative):

> InfluxDB calculates the difference between chronological field values and converts those results into the rate of change per unit.

So to me, that means that the value at a given point should not change that much when expanding the time view, since the value should be *rate of change per unit* (1s in my example query above).

In graphite, they have the specific `perSecond` function, which works much better:

`perSecond(consolidateBy(my_counter, 'max'))`

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong with the influx query above?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want per second results that don't vary, you'll want to `GROUP BY time(1s)`. This will give you accurate `perSecond` results.

Consider the following example:

Suppose that the value of the counter at each second changes like so

```
0s → 1s → 2s → 3s → 4s
1  → 2  → 5  → 8  → 11
```

Depending on how we group the sequence above, we'll see different results.

Consider the case where we group things into `2s` buckets.

```
 0s-2s   →    2s-4s
(5-1)/2  →  (11-5)/2
   2     →      3
```

versus the `1s` buckets

```
 0s-1s  →  1s-2s  →  2s-3s  →  3s-4s
(2-1)/1 → (5-2)/1 → (8-5)/1 → (11-8)/1
   1    →    3    →    3    →    3
```

Addressing

> > So to me, that means that the value at a given point should not change that much when expanding the time view, since the value should be rate of change per unit (1s in my example query above).

The `rate of change per unit` is a normalizing factor, independent of the `GROUP BY` time unit. Interpreting our previous example when we change the derivative interval to `2s` may offer some insight.

The exact equation is

```
∆y/(∆x/tu)
```

Consider the case where we group things into `1s` buckets with a derivative interval of `2s`. The result we should see is

```
 0s-1s    →  1s-2s    →  2s-3s    →  3s-4s
2*(2-1)/1 → 2*(5-2)/1 → 2*(8-5)/1 → (11-8)/1
   2      →    6      →    6      →    6
```

This may seem a bit odd, but if you consider what this says it should make sense. When we specify a derivative interval of `2s` what we're asking for is what the `2s` rate of change is for the `1s` `GROUP BY` bucket.

If we apply similar reasoning to the case of `2s` buckets with a derivative interval of `2s` is then

```
 0s-2s     →    2s-4s
2*(5-1)/2  →  2*(11-5)/2
   4       →      6
```

What we're asking for here is what the `2s` rate of change is for the `2s` `GROUP BY` bucket and in the first interval the `2s` rate of change would be `4` and the second interval the `2s` rate of change would be `6`.

Comment: As a followup, for your solution, when doing the `group by time (1s)`, one should _not_ specify a internal in the non_negative_derivative, correct? So: `non_negative_derivative(last("EnqueueCount")) AS "EnqueueRate" ... group by (1s)`

Answer (score 9):

@Michael-Desa gives an excellent explanation.

I'd like to augment that answer with a solution to a pretty common metric our company is interested in: "What is the **maximum** "operation per second" value on a specific measurement field?".

I will use a real-life example from our company.

### Scenario Background

We send a lot of data from an RDBMS to [redis](http://redis.io/). When transferring that data, we keep track of 5 counters:

1. `TipTrgUp` -> Updates by a business trigger (stored procedure)
2. `TipTrgRm` -> Removes by a business trigger (stored procedure)
3. `TipRprUp` -> Updates by an unattended auto-repair batch process
4. `TipRprRm` -> Removes by an unattended auto-repair batch process
5. `TipDmpUp` -> Updates by a bulk-dump process

We made a metrics collector that sends the current state of these counters to InfluxDB, with an interval of 1 second (configurable).

### Grafana graph 1: low resolution, no true max ops

Here is the grafana query that is useful, but does not show the true max ops when zoomed out (we know it will go to around 500 ops on a normal business day, when no special dumps or maintenance is taking place - otherwise it goes into the thousands):

```sql
SELECT
    non_negative_derivative(max(TipTrgUp),1s) AS "update/TipTrgUp"
   ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipTrgRm),1s) AS "remove/TipTrgRm"
   ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipRprUp),1s) AS "autorepair-up/TipRprUp"
   ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipRprRm),1s) AS "autorepair-rm/TipRprRm"
   ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipDmpUp),1s) AS "dump/TipDmpUp"
FROM "$rp"."redis_flux_-transid-d-s"
WHERE
    host =~ /$server$/
    AND $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval),* fill(null)
```

*Sidenotes: `$rp` is the name of the retention policy, templated in grafana. We use CQ's to downsample to retention policies with a larger duration. Also note the `1s` as a derivative parameter: it is needed, since the default is different when using GROUP BY. This can be easily overlooked in the InfluxDB documentation.*

The graph, seen by 24 hours looks like this:
[image]

If we simply use a resolution of 1s (as suggested by @Michael-Desa), an enormous amount of data is transferred from influxdb to the client. It works reasonably well (about 10 seconds), but too slow for us.

### Grafana graph 2: low and high resolution, true max ops, slow performance

We can however use **subqueries** to add the true maxops to this graph, which is a slight improvement. A lot less data is transferred to the client, but the InfluxDB server has to do a lot of number crunching. Series B (with `maxops` prepended in the aliases):

```sql
SELECT
    max(subTipTrgUp) AS maxopsTipTrgUp
   ,max(subTipTrgRm) AS maxopsTipTrgRm
   ,max(subTipRprUp) AS maxopsRprUp
   ,max(subTipRprRm) AS maxopsTipRprRm
   ,max(subTipDmpUp) AS maxopsTipDmpUp
FROM (
    SELECT
        non_negative_derivative(max(TipTrgUp),1s) AS subTipTrgUp
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipTrgRm),1s) AS subTipTrgRm
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipRprUp),1s) AS subTipRprUp
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipRprRm),1s) AS subTipRprRm
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipDmpUp),1s) AS subTipDmpUp
    FROM "$rp"."redis_flux_-transid-d-s"
    WHERE
        host =~ /$server$/
        AND $timeFilter
    GROUP BY time(1s),* fill(null)
)
WHERE $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval),* fill(null)
```

Gives:
[image]

### Grafana graph 3: low and high resolution, true max ops, high performance, pre-calculate by CQ

Our final solution to these kind of metrics (but only when we need a live view, the subquery approach works fine for ad-hoc graphs) is: use a Continuous Query to pre-calculate the true maxops. We generate CQ's like this:

```sql
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY "redis_flux_-transid-d-s.maxops.1s"
ON telegraf
BEGIN
    SELECT
        non_negative_derivative(max(TipTrgUp),1s) AS TipTrgUp
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipTrgRm),1s) AS TipTrgRm
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipRprUp),1s) AS TipRprUp
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipRprRm),1s) AS TipRprRm
       ,non_negative_derivative(max(TipDmpUp),1s) AS TipDmpUp
    INTO telegraf.A."redis_flux_-transid-d-s.maxops"
    FROM telegraf.A."redis_flux_-transid-d-s"
    GROUP BY time(1s),*
END
```

From here on, it's trivial to use these maxops measurements in grafana. When downsampling to an RP with longer retention, we again use `max()` as the selector function.

Series B (with `.maxops` appended in the aliases)

```sql
SELECT
    max(TipTrgUp) AS "update/TipTrgUp.maxops"
   ,max(TipTrgRm) AS "remove/TipTrgRm.maxops"
   ,max(TipRprUp) as "autorepair-up/TipRprUp.maxops"
   ,max(TipRprRm) as "autorepair-rm/TipRprRm.maxops"
   ,max(TipDmpUp) as "dump/TipDmpUp.maxops"
FROM "$rp"."redis_flux_-transid-d-s.maxops"
WHERE
    host =~ /$server$/
    AND $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval),* fill(null)
```

Gives:
[image]

When zoomed in to 1s precision, you can see that the graphs become identical:
[image]

Hope this helps, TW

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the `$__interval` width changes depending on the time frame you are viewing in Grafana.

The way then to get consistent results is to take a sample from each interval (`mean()`, `median()`, or `max()` all work equally well) and then transform by `derivative($__interval)`. That way your derivative changes to match your interval length as you zoom in/out.

So, your query might look like:

```
SELECT derivative(mean("mem.gc.count"), $__interval) FROM "influxdb"
WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time($__interval) fill(null)
```