# Speed rates on Grafana, influxdb

Tags: monitoring, influxdb, grafana, collectd

Details:

- Grafana version: 2.5.0
- Datasource: influxdb
- OS: ubuntu server 14.04

I was trying to get the current speed rate in megabit/s from a server interface but I cannot figure out how to transform "if_octets" in Megabit/s using Grafana. Or better I don't know what query to use.

I used this query but I have no output

```
select derivative(mean(value), 1s) from "interface_rx" where "istance" ='em1' and "type" = 'if_octects' and time > now() - 4h group by time(1m)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you the number of `if_octets/s`.

```
select derivative(sum(value), 1s) ... group by time(1s)
```

Essentially, for each second we want to sum together all of the values in the previous second, and take the rate of change of that value.

See this description of the [derivative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016051/how-do-i-get-consistent-values-with-influxdb-non-negative-derivative/38018535#38018535) for more details on why we want to `group by time(1s)`.